# Control characters are not allowed error when using OCI for Config Sync in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/how-to/sync-oci-artifacts-from-artifact-registry#oras) in order to set up Config Sync in GKE to set up a RootSync through an OCI image. I have created a test-namespace file as instructed, packaged it up, and pushed it to Artifact Registry using both *crane* and *oras*, however when I apply the Root Sync object I am met with the below error:

```
errors:
- code: "2001"
  errorMessage: |-
    KNV2001: yaml: control characters are not allowed

    path: /repo/source/<My Artifact Registry numeric ID?>/._test-namespace.yaml

    For more information, see https://g.co/cloud/acm-errors#knv2001
```

So it seems that the '*_*' character has somehow been added to the beginning of the file name, but I am not entirely sure why or how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same documentation and ran into the same issue.

It seems to be the fault of `tar` on macOS and how mac handles files.

You can get around this by using `--disable-copyfile` with the tar command.

```bash
tar --disable-copyfile -cf test-namespace.tar test-namespace.yaml
```

And then use crane / oras as normal.

---

Related thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282055/a-lot-of-files-inside-a-tar